# Return statement not executed when valid member number is entered

Tags: python, json, file, class, methods

Morning all,

So I've tried to create an account class with a scan method that takes a "fictitious" scanning of a members card, however, when I enter a valid card_number in the input field it returns another input field, yet if I enter an invalid card_number it returns Invalid ID

Here is my code, where am I going wrong please?

```
from enum import Enum
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import csv
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

membersJsonPath = 'members.json'

class BookStatus(Enum):
  AVAILABLE, RESERVED, LOANED, LOST = 1, 2, 3, 4

class ReservationStatus(Enum):
  WAITING, PENDING, CANCELED, NONE = 1, 2, 3, 4

class AccountStatus(Enum):
  ACTIVE, CLOSED, CANCELED, NONE = 1, 2, 3, 4

class Account(ABC):
    def __init__(self, status=AccountStatus.ACTIVE):
        self.__id = self.scan_id()
        self.__status = status
        
    def scan_id(self):
      with open(membersJsonPath, 'r') as membersJson:
        data = json.load(membersJson)
        input_id = input("Please enter your member ID: ")
        for member in data['members']:
          if member['card_number'] == input_id:
            return ("Welcome, " + member['first_name'] + "!") 
          else:
            return "Invalid ID"

a = Account()
a.scan_id()
```

Here is a portion of the json file that I created from a CSV file

```
{
    "members": [
        {
            "\u00ef\u00bb\u00bfid": "1",
            "first_name": "Adelaide",
            "last_name": "Cunningham",
            "gender": "Female",
            "email": "a.cunningham@randatmail.com",
            "card_number": "13"
        },
        {
            "\u00ef\u00bb\u00bfid": "2",
            "first_name": "Charlie",
            "last_name": "Roberts",
            "gender": "Male",
            "email": "c.roberts@randatmail.com",
            "card_number": "22"
        },
        {
            "\u00ef\u00bb\u00bfid": "3",
            "first_name": "Eric",
            "last_name": "Cooper",
            "gender": "Male",
            "email": "e.cooper@randatmail.com",
            "card_number": "33"
        },
        {
            "\u00ef\u00bb\u00bfid": "4",
            "first_name": "Cadie",
            "last_name": "Hall",
            "gender": "Female",
            "email": "c.hall@randatmail.com",
            "card_number": "43"
        }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Your `__init__` method is calling `self.scan_id()` and then you call it again after you instantiate with `a.scan_id()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this for loop:

```
for member in data['members']:
    if member['card_number'] == input_id:
        return ("Welcome, " + member['first_name'] + "!") 
    else:
        return "Invalid ID"
```

Here, if the `input_id` is equal to the first member's card number, it returns the welcome message, otherwise `"Invalid ID"`. You want to scan all card numbers, and only return `"Invalid ID"` if none of them match, so the second return statement should be after the end of the for loop:

```
for member in data['members']:
    if member['card_number'] == input_id:
        return ("Welcome, " + member['first_name'] + "!") 
    
return "Invalid ID"
```